# Comment with more than 1 @user fails?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

Just repeatedly tried to add a comment which references two @users. The usual message box pops up saying only one will be notified but as of today, the comment is not posted. If I remove one of the @users it is accepted and posted.

Comment: only I don't think "off topic" is quite right ...

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.

Answer (score 2):

This is status by design

[Please change comment notification to notify multiple people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94872/please-change-comment-notification-to-notify-multiple-people)

And for a lot more information see this post on meta.stackoverflow.com

[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020)

Comment: That only 1 user gets notified, I get. But why is the posting of the comment blocked?

Comment: That's just what they chose to do. I would have to defer to the SE team for why they chose to do it that way. I think they block it to prevent a false sense of security, thinking that two would get notified because two are mentioned.